# Could not find or load main class testABCD

Tags: java

I have create one java application and also import selenium server standalone jar
my class name is Abc in side the calss one Testing program that open Firefox browser, some athor task...

also i have Run configuration and run but it give error main class not fount

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class Abc {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "https://www.google.co.in/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test
  public void testABCD() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "about:home");
    driver.findElement(By.id("searchText")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("searchText")).sendKeys("google.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("searchSubmit")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail - Google")).click();
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
  }

  private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
      driver.findElement(by);
      return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private boolean isAlertPresent() {
    try {
      driver.switchTo().alert();
      return true;
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
    try {
      Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
      String alertText = alert.getText();
      if (acceptNextAlert) {
        alert.accept();
      } else {
        alert.dismiss();
      }
      return alertText;
    } finally {
      acceptNextAlert = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to run it with "Junit" launcher configuration

Comment: I think @alias_boubou is right, but you provide some more details. What do you mean you have a "Run Configuration"? Which IDE are you using? What are you doing, exactly? What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

You present a class named `ABC`, and no others.  You report (in your question title) that the complaint is that a class `testABC` cannot be found.  Based on what you have said and presented, I don't see why the error message should be surprising.  There is no class `testABC` to be found.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am mistaken, but is the compiler complaining about main CLASS not found or main method not found? If you want to execute your class you need

```
public static void main(String args[]){
//something
}
```

or am I totally wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't creating a standalone program, instead you wrote junit test.

Since you are using junit test cases, if you are using Junit 4, then you should run by command line as:

```
java -cp .:<path to junit*.jar> org.junit.runner.JUnitCore Abc
```

While if you are using Junit 3, then you should use:

```
java -cp .:<path to junit*.jar> junit.textui.TestRunner Abc
```

Note: Prerequisite to this is you have already compiled the junit test case and you already have class file.

If you are using IDE like eclipse (since you said run configuration), you should click on run as -> junit test.